# Actuating servos with a timer

Tags: arduino

I am trying to figure out the best way to turn a servo after setting it to a clock. If you have seen the KitchenSafe it would work the same way. I want to be able to set a digital timer that would lock when set then enlock when the time goes out. It needs to be battery powered from something like AA batteries. 
THx

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `millis()`; it will keep track of the nuber of millisecods from the powerup of the arduino.

At the user input you get the actual millis() value and activate the servo, then when `millis()-startTime > timeout`, where timeout is your fixed time, you activate again the servo. very easy to do